# Request to Repost After Accidental Deletion

Tags: support

I have a question about my Academia Stack Exchange post: [Applying to Ph.D. programs: Should I include my master's degree transcript?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/99211/applying-to-ph-d-programs-should-i-include-my-masters-degree-transcript)

I think I accidentally deleted my question, as my question was transferred over from the math stack exchange (no one told me) and I didn't want to post the same question twice, so I wanted to delete it from the match stack exchange, but ended up deleting it from here. Now I am not allowed to repost it.

The question is incredibly important to me, on topic, and likely important to many in my same position. May I repost?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done. Welcome to AC.SE. In the future, you can also flag the question for moderator attention.

Usually you would be able to undelete your own question, but in this case I think something funky happens because of the migration. No big deal.

Comment: Thank you! You were very helpful.

Comment: @Daniel just to get into the SE state of mind, upvotes and accepting answers are the way we say thanks. When you get a chance take a look at our [help].

Comment: I definitely tried. It won't let me (too little reputation to up vote).